# Is slandering major sin in Islam and their Prayers wont be accepted?

Tags: muslim-practices

One of my relatives always prays on time and fasts and wear hijab, but she slanders her relatives and she talked bad about my cousins so they wont get married. Her life is very hard and she always fights with her sister.